# HTML canvas responds to click+drag by creating an expanding-box selector

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs, fabricjs

I've been learning a little bit about HTML Canvas and I've run into a behavior that seems to be cross-browser (Chrome, Firefox, Safari) - but seems unique to certain setups.

The issue is that in some cases when I perform a click-drag movement with the mouse, in addition to whatever event interaction that happens on the canvas - inexplicably an expanding-box is also drawn (like when you select multiple icons on your desktop).

I ran into this behavior with [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) and spun my wheels for a long time thinking it was something I did wrong (granted, it may still be) - but I switched over to kineticjs and the problem went away. But I'm seeing it in other places and I'm wondering how/if I can fix it without having to switch libraries.

I have some live examples as well:

- fabric.js: http://www.remix.net/matrix/index.broken.html - A click-drag invokes the box-select behavior.
- kineticjs: http://www.remix.net/matrix/index.html - Click-drag works fine?

I'm on OSX, but I'd be curious if windows users see the same behavior as well. (If anyone is feeling charitable with their time to take a look at the pages)

[image: example]

Comment: Are you sure you meant "kinect" instead of "kinetic"?

Comment: You are correct. Edited my question accordingly.

Comment: In win7+IE10, your fabricJS example is no-op (no dragging/no extra bounding box/no nothing).  Your kineticJS example will toggle highlighting for any rect that's dragged over (no extra bounding box visible). Note: fast drags will cause the Kinetic example to fail to toggle some rects.

Comment: In win7+Chrome, your fabricJS shows your rects and does have the extra bounding boxes and does not toggle any rects.  Your kineticJS example works and doesn't show the extra bounding boxes, but dragging appears somewhat unresponsive because only every other rect is toggled.

Comment: In win7+Mozilla, your fabricJS shows your rects and does have the extra bounding boxes and does not toggle any rects. Your kineticJS example works and doesn't show the extra bounding boxes, but dragging appears greatly unresponsive because only an occasional rect is toggled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blue selection box is a default behavior in Fabric (grouping objects), for interactive canvases (`fabric.Canvas`).

But you can disable it via `canvas.selection = false`.

Here's a quick example of drawing lines, without interfering selection box (see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Ctab/2/)):

[image]

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { selection: false });

var line, isDown;

canvas.on('mouse:down', function(o){
  isDown = true;
  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
  var points = [ pointer.x, pointer.y, pointer.x, pointer.y ];
  line = new fabric.Line(points, {
    strokeWidth: 5,
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 'red'
  });
  canvas.add(line);
});

canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o){
  if (!isDown) return;
  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
  line.set({ x2: pointer.x, y2: pointer.y });
  canvas.renderAll();
});

canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o){
  isDown = false;
});
```